# Django 1.1 equivalent of the 'in' operator

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to display a piece of HTML only if a variable value appears in a list. I know that Django 1.2 has an 'in' operator. But I am working on a Google App Engine app. Is there a workaround I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own template tag to achieve it or put it in your controller's logic.

Have a look at this snippet: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/302/

Answer (score 0):

If what you need to know is whether you should render a piece of HTML, and you are going to reuse this rule in other templates, you may try to use `django.template.RequestContext` and make it an accessable status variable in templates in need.

```
def context(request):
    return {'render_a_panel' : request.user.username in ('Jim', 'Tom')}
```

Of course, this only works if your rule is based on request.